# Large Delphi exe and maintenance issues

Tags: delphi

I have a project with hundreds of VCL forms, when compile it the exe size is around 80MB which is not an issue. When a customer askes for an update on a single form or debugging a single form then updating 80mb for a single change is a big issue.

What are possible options or good practices to split these forms in  different files and loading them from one exe.
And when any change is needed then send/update that particular form or section.

Delphi 10.1 berlin
And I always send release file.

Thanks

Comment: Use an install program that can deliver patches.

Comment: As @David said, use a program that can write patches. Or, if you really want to modularize your monolithic program, use packages. You will probably not put every form in its own package, but how you divide things up is up to you.

Comment: Trying to turn your app into a jigsaw of modules leads to pain. Don't do it.

Comment: How do you send a new exe file build to your customer?
Is it possible to pack the file?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan can you suggest any.

Comment: @AlexKalabukhov I send it normally using 7z like compressors.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't allow recommendations. That's what websearch is for.

Answer (score 0):

try to split up your application into packages (.Bpl-files).

[Here is an example how to do this.](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+II+Delphi+Object-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+10+Libraries+and+Packages/Forms+Inside+Packages/)

Comment: Perhaps some downvoters could suggest improvements to this answer?

Comment: I avoid breaking up a project into packages because it increases the chances of certain pieces getting out of sync as you upgrade. I don't worry too much about the size of the executables any more.

Comment: @Bruce: I guess it helps (avoiding upgrade woes) if you give your packages appropriate suffixes, just like Delphi itself does. That does mean that a full upgrade means you must distribute a completely new set of packages too, but it still makes updating (e.g. to fix bugs) easier, IMO. Sure, a monolithic project can be preferred, but may not work for those who have limited Internet access, as is still the case in many places on earth.

Comment: I guess the downvoters think the answer is a little too simple. A little more explanation would help improve the answer. The link should only be there to illustrate or to be used for further reading. It should not be the main content.

Comment: @Bruce Personally, I'd love to see an explanation for the upvote, that gave a reason based on the content of the answer.

Comment: @Rudy: If I distribute all packages to make sure that nothing gets out of sync, then I'm actually sending more bytes than if I'm sending a monolithic executable. Otherwise, different customers have different binaries in their installations and I can't be sure that any problem they are seeing isn't related. It's actually bitten me back in the D7 days, which is why I avoid it now.

Comment: @David: I didn't upvote. I just added my opinion on why packages are a bad idea for this purpose in my experience.

Comment: @Bruce: you only send *all* packages during an *upgrade* (a new version). You only send specific packages when you do an *update* (e.g. to fix bugs). Of course a complete upgrade with packages is larger than a monolithic program.

Comment: @Rudy: I understand the theory. It just hasn't always proven foolproof in practice.

Comment: @Bruce: nothing is completely foolproof. This is a fight between you and the universe, and the universe can always come up with bigger fools. <g>

Comment: @BruceMcGee Many moons ago, my colleague and I were using the package approach in order to distribute additional functionality without (in theory) having to change the main executable.  It's a maintenance nightmare compounded by having to build different versions of the RTL packages when patching bugs

Comment: Hello, this was my first answer to a question at stackoverflow. I was wondering why my answer was down-voted. It's a clear answer to the question.

Comment: It's terse and offers little beyond and off site link